# Django create template filter for nice time

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I know there's `timesince` filter.

But I want something that returns this:

- just few seconds ago
- X minutes ago
- X hours ago
- on $day_name
- X weeks ago
- X months ago

Examples:

- just few seconds ago
- 37 minutes ago
- 2 hours ago
- yesterday
- on Thursday
- 1 week ago
- 7 months ago

How can I implement something like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if it ticks all your boxes, but there's a tag **naturaltime** in the django.contrib.humanize template tags that should do this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'django.contrib.humanize',
}
```

**template.html**

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ model.timefield|naturaltime }}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this. This was added after Django 1.3; you'll have to get it from SVN trunk.

Comment: Awesome, I like Django more and more ;)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: If you are using a recent SVN checkout of Django (post 1.3), see the answer by Pastylegs. Otherwise, here is what you can do:

I use [repoze.timeago](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.timeago/0.5) for this purpose. The code is fairly straightforward, so you could customize it if needed.

Here is a Django custom filter called `elapsed` that I created that uses repoze.timeago.

```
import datetime
from django import template
import repoze.timeago

register = template.Library()

# If you aren't using UTC time everywhere, this line can be used
# to customize repoze.timeago:
repoze.timeago._NOW = datetime.datetime.now

@register.filter(name='elapsed')
def elapsed(timestamp):
    """
    This filter accepts a datetime and computes an elapsed time from "now".
    The elapsed time is displayed as a "humanized" string.
    Examples:
        1 minute ago
        5 minutes ago
        1 hour ago
        10 hours ago
        1 day ago
        7 days ago

    """
    return repoze.timeago.get_elapsed(timestamp)
elapsed.is_safe = True
```